# Number of sequences in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose you have a graph with $N$ branches in parallel each with $M$ nodes. Given that it is possible to remove one of the leaf nodes every time, how many ordered sequences of removed nodes is it possible to create?

As an illustration, here is a graph where $N=2$ and $M=3$. In this case, we could enumerate 20 different sequences.

[image: sample graph]

For other cases, we have enumerated: 6, with $N=2$ and $M=2$, and 90 when $M=2$ and $N=3$. However, we cannot really come up with a way of generalising it to higher values of $M$ and $N$. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sequence is completely described by listing in order the number of the branch from which each leaf is deleted. Such sequences of branch numbers are sequences of length $MN$ consisting of $M$ copies of each integer in $\{1,\ldots,N\}$. In other words, you want to count the number of $MN$-sequences containing each $k\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$ exactly $M$ times. There are $\binom{MN}M$ ways to choose the $M$ positions for $1$, then $\binom{M(N-1)}M$ ways to choose the $M$ places for $2$, and so on, for a grand total of

$$\binom{MN}{\underbrace{M,\ldots,M}_N}=\frac{(MN)!}{M!^N}\tag{1}$$

sequences. (The object on the lefthand side of $(1)$ is a [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).)